# Why solidity's keccak returns different value from online generators?

Tags: remix, keccak, solidity-0.5.x

I try to implement my own little modifited commit&reveal voting. I have problem with revael phase. Reveal metod signature look like:

```
function reveal(bytes32[] memory _reveals, bytes32[] memory _commits)
```

So I need to compare hashed reveal phrase and commit phrase. I discover that these hashes do not match each other.

**To demonstrate my problem I created this contract:**

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.10;

contract Utils{
   event HashedData(bytes32);

   function getHash(bytes32 data) public pure returns(bytes32){
       return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(data));
   }

   function checkHash(bytes32 hash, bytes32 data) public returns(bool){
        bytes32 hashedData = getHash(data);
        emit HashedData(hashedData);
        return hash==hashedData;
    }
}
```

Example input data:
phrase: "*1_john*" to `bytes32`

> data: 0x315f6b6f74000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

hash from data (without `0x`)

> hash: 0x90a0076f07f9884805bdc4d668c55756ff42238a0ad7b824b8a267783e822544

As result I receive:
[image]

Where I made mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you treated `"315f6b6f74000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"` like a string instead of the hexadecimal byte sequence it actually is.

Via web3 0.2.x:

```js
web3.sha3('315f6b6f74000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
> "0x90a0076f07f9884805bdc4d668c55756ff42238a0ad7b824b8a267783e822544"
web3.sha3('315f6b6f74000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', { encoding: 'hex' })
> "0x1a32a86fd2fa1e85655c2d86eadd160787458aff3d70eefae6150b79b648693f"
```

Note that the second value is correct, once you interpret it as hexadecimal. If the tool you're using doesn't support hexadecimal inputs, you'll need to find a different tool.